# Maven java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: maven, filenotfoundexception

I'm developing a project with Maven. In a class to send e-mails, in run and dev modes, I get the following error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jQuery/images/logo.png (Ficheiro ou directoria inexistente) ==> translation = File or directory not found.

I've tryed lots of paths, like "./jQuery/images/logo.png", "/jQuery/images/logo.png" and others. The full relative path is: "src/main/webapp/jQuery/images/logo.png".

In "target" folder, the path is "project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jQuery/images/logo.png".
Inside war file, is "jQuery/images/logo.png".

I don't think it's important, but I'm using NetBeans 7.1.1 as IDE.

I found that the absolute path returned in runtime is "/home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/jQuery/images/logo.png"!... It's not the project path!

How can I get a file in webapp folder and descendents from a Java class, in a Maven project?

The code is:

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = null;
        FileDataSource fileDataSource = null;
        for (File a : attachments) {
            System.out.println(a.getAbsolutePath());

            attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(a) {

                @Override
                public String getContentType() {
                    return "application/octet-stream";
                }
            };
            attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
            attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName());

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        }

        msg.setContent(multipart);
        msg.saveChanges();

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, "password");
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: Show the code that you're using to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `.../apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/jQuery/...` is really odd. `bin` contains scripts for Tomcat, it should not contain any code nor any resources related to your application. Even if you deploy your app in the context `/bin`, the resources would end up under `` `.../apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps/bin/... ``

This looks like a mistake made in an earlier deployment.

Now back to your question. To get the path of resource of your web app, use this code:

```
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/jQuery/images/logo.png");
```

([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29))

Comment: I'm not using a servlet. Is a regular Java class, if I can call it like that... public class EmailsManager {...}

Comment: In that class, with System.getProperty("java.class.path") I get: /home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/rcc/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/tomcat-juli.jar. What this means?

Comment: Well, we did it! Thank you Aaron. I used your suggestion in the JSP that calls the Java class. The new code used in JSP is:

    String attachment = (String) request.getParameter("attachment"); // single demo file
    
    String attachmentRealPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(attachment + "/");
    
    ArrayList<File> attachments = new ArrayList();
    attachments.add(new File(attachmentRealPath));    
    
    EmailsManager emails = new EmailsManager(host,port,from,to,subject,bodyText,attachments);

Comment: Sorry, the code lines should be separated, but I didn't find the way to do that.